# Custom AccessDenied Using Web.config

Tags: 2010

For some reasons i find my self facing this request :
Making a redirect from : /_Layouts/AccessDenied.aspx to a Custom ApplicationPage
and the modification MUST be done ONLY on web.config which means that i can't use

```
UpdateMappedPage(SPWebApplication.SPCustomPage.AccessDenied, customAccessDeniedPage)
```

or any of the solutions on this [site](http://solutionz4u.blogspot.com/2012/07/set-custom-application-page.html)

After some research i tried to add this :

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/_layouts/AccessDenied.aspx">
<error redirect="~/_layouts/MySite/Pages/AccessDenied.aspx" statusCode="401" />
<error redirect="~/_layouts/MySite/Pages/AccessDenied.aspx" statusCode="403" />
</customErrors>
```

And this :

```
<system.webServer>
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Auto">
</httpErrors>
```

but it didn't make a redirect, even if, under the IIS --> MySite the redirect exist !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it can be done.  I'm pretty sure the sharepoint httpmodule is what redirects for errors and accessdenied pages.  So it ignores what's in the web.config.